# Refactoring document.ready to Object

Tags: jquery, refactoring

I am finally learning how to take a HUGE $(document).ready() and refactor it into a readable and manageable object. I am currently refactoring the handlers and I can't find anything on how to handle parameters.

In the document.ready, I have this function:

```
$('#corporate_addressbook').on('keypress', '#corp_search', function(e){
    var val =  $(this).val();
    if( e.keyCode == 13 && val.length > 0){
        $('#main_content').hide();
        $('#other_content').show();
    } // end if
});
```

I can refactor that to

```
$('#corporate_addressbook').on('keypress', '#corp_search', this.showOther);
```

and add the method showOther as:

```
showOther: function(){
    $('#main_content').hide();
    $('#other_content').show();
}
```

Where I am lost is how/where do I do the check for the enter key and if there is a value like in the original eventhandler.

Since I need to pass the event and the value, I tried and failed with this:

```
$('#corporate_addressbook').on('keypress', '#corp_search', this.showOther(evt, $('#corp_search').val() ));
```

Any help is appreciated.

==UPDATE==
Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="main_content">
    <div id="main_left" style="float:left; width: 65%; min-height:100px; padding:10px 10px 0 20px;">
         <div id='edr_news' class='edr_web_part'>
        <h1>LATEST <span class='thickTtl'>NEWS</span></h1>
        <div class='ewp_inner'></div>
         </div> <!-- /#edr_news -->

         <div id='corp_cal' class='edr_web_part'>
        <h1>EdR <span class='thickTtl'>CALENDAR</span></h1>
            <div class='ewp_inner'></div>
         </div> <!-- /#corp_cal -->
    </div> <!-- /#main_left -->
    <div id="main_right" style="float:right; width:30%; min-height:100px; padding:10px 10px;">
        <div id='corporate_addressbook' class='edr_web_part'>
            <h1>CORPORATE <span class='thickTtl'>DIRECTORY</span></h1>
                <div class='ewp_inner'>
                    <span class='book_instructions'>Search by First and/or Last Name</span>
                    <form id="frm_corp_search">
                        <input id='corp_search' class='searchBar' style='width:83%;' />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <img src='/SiteAssets/find.png' alt='find' id='btnFindCorp' />
                    </form>
                    <div id='corp_show'></div>
                </div>
        </div> <!-- /#corporate_addressbook -->
        <div id='property_addressbook' class='edr_web_part'>
            <h1>PROPERTY <span class='thickTtl'>DIRECTORY</span></h1>
            <div class='ewp_inner'>
                <span class='book_instructions'>Search by Property Number or Staff Name</span>
                <form id="frm_prop_search">
                    <input id='prop_search' class='searchBar' style='width:83%;' />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <img src='/SiteAssets/find.png' alt='find' id='btnFindProp' />
                </form>
                <div id='prop_show'></div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /#property_addressbook -->
        <div id='edr_links' class='edr_web_part'>
            <h1>IMPORTANT <span class='thickTtl'>LINKS</span></h1>
            <div class='ewp_inner'>
                <ul></ul>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /#edr_links -->
    </div> <!-- /#main_right -->
</div> <!-- /#main_content -->

<div id="other_content" style="display:none;">
    <div id="other_left" style="float:left; width: 100%; padding:0 10px 0 20px;">
        <h1>Other Content</h1>
        <button id="btnGoHome">HOME</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my entire main.js

```
var home = {
    init: function(){
        //remove target='_blank' from Paid Holidays
        $('#edr_links').find('a:contains("Paid Holidays")').attr("target", "");

        $('.ms-core-sideNavBox-removeLeftMargin').css('display', 'none');
        $('#contentBox').css('margin-left', '0' );

        $('#btnFindCorp').on('click', this.showOther);
        $('#btnFindProp').on('click', this.showOther);

        $('#btnGoHome').on('click', this.showHome);

        $('#corporate_addressbook').on('keypress', '#corp_search', function(e){
            var val =  $(this).val();
            if( e.keyCode == 13 && val.length > 0){
                this.showOther;
            } // end if
        });

        $('#property_addressbook').on('keypress', '#prop_search', function(e){
            var val = $(this).val();
            if( e.keyCode == 13 &&  val.length > 0){
                this.showOther;
            } // end if
        });
    },

    showOther: function(){
        $('#main_content').hide();
        $('#other_content').show();
    },

    showHome: function(){
        $('#other_content').hide();
        $('#main_content').show();
    }
};

$(document).ready( function(){
    home.init();
});
```

I am no longer triggering anything with the enter key for either input.

AGAIN, thank all of you for helping me learn this!!!

Comment: The structure of the function should be the same whether it's named or anonymous. Give it the same argument list, and assign `val` in the same way.

Comment: The answer was deleted before I could get the way to use an anonymous function to pass the parameters in the first place.

Comment: There is no anonymous function in the refactored version. Just define the named function in the same way that you defined the original anonymous function.

Comment: The arguments are passed automatically by the browser. It does it the same way whether the function is named or anonymous.

Comment: Please forgive me for stumbling here but I know that I am learning a great thing here and I want to get it right. I will update my original question with my refactored code because I missed something and the enter key is no longer triggering anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
showOther: function(e) {
    var val =  $(this).val();
    if( e.keyCode == 13 && val.length > 0){
        $('#main_content').hide();
        $('#other_content').show();
}
```

As you can see, the named function is identical to the original anonymous function.

UPDATE:

If you want to use `showOther` for non-keypress events, you could leave the function as you defined it, and change the binding to:

```
$('#corporate_addressbook').on('keypress', '#corp_search', (function(that) {
    return function(e){
        var val =  $(this).val();
        if( e.keyCode == 13 && val.length > 0){
            that.showOther();
        }
    };
})(this));
```

You need to use this IIFE to capture the value of `this` from the object in the local variable `that`, because when the event handler is called `that` will be set to the target of the event.

Comment: I see that BUT I can't seem to grasp how it still knows that $(this) is the input that triggered the method

Comment: When jQuery calls an event handler, it binds `this` to the input that triggered it.

Comment: PLUS I am trying to use showOther in two ways -- one when a button is clicked (so no keyCode or value) and one when the user types a name and hits enter

Answer (score 2):

Change your `showOther` function to accept the `event` parameter:

```
showOther: function(e) {
```

This will be automatically passed to your function when it is called.